# Does a backdraft component have any visibility into the dom element where it's being inserted?

Tags: javascript, backdraftjs

Using [backdraftjs](https://backdraftjs.org/) I want to do a customized fancy select widget similar to chosen.js.

My thought was that I could have markup like this:

```
<div id="bobSelect">
     <select name="bob">
          <option>Bob Crane</option>
          <option>Bob Hope</option>
          <option>Bob Melvin</option>
          <option>Bob Dobbs</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Then I'd replace it via something like

```
render(FancySelectComponent, {}, 'bobSelect', 'replace');
```

...and in `FancySelectComponent` I would grab things like the options from `bobSelect`.

However it looks like there's no way for `FancySelectComponent` to have visibility into the dom element where it will eventually be inserted. Is that right?

So instead maybe in render I need to do something like

```
render(FancySelectComponent, {basedOn: 'bobSelect'}, 'bobSelect', 'replace');
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; as written,

```
render(FancySelectComponent, {}, 'bobSelect', 'replace');
```

FancySelectComponent's constructor is not provided any information about the existing DOM tree rooted at `div#bobSelect`. In fact, the render application above is just syntax sugar for...

```
let result = new FancySelectComponent({});
let replacedNode = document.getElementById('bobSelect');
let parentNode = replacedNode.parentNode;
parentNode.removeChild(replacedNode);
parentNode.appendChild(result.render());
return result;
```

(note: in your example, both the replaced and replacing node are single nodes, but render can handle cases when either or both are a forrest of nodes)

You are also correct that, if you want access to the existing `div#bobSelect`, then you can pass it directly to the constructor via the second argument to render:

```
render(
  FancySelectComponent, 
  {replacingDiv:document.getElementById('bobSelect')}, 
  'bobSelect', 
  'replace'
);
```